# Как работать с `out` параметрами методов при `Setup`/`Verify` этих методов в мок-классе?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, moq

```
public class MyClass
{
   public virtual void Method1(string par1, int par2)
   {
      // ...

      var result = new Dictionary<byte, string>();
      for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
         if(someCondition) break;
         Method2(par1, out byte res1, out string res2);
         result[res1] = res2;
      }

      // ...
   }

   public virtual void Method2(string par1, out byte res1, out string res2)
   {
      // ...

      res1 = 1;
      res2 = "res2";

      // ...
   }
}
```

---

```
    // test class
public class MyClassTests
{
   [Fact]
   public void TestMethod()
   {
      string par1 = "value";
      int par2 = 2;
      var myClassMock = new Mock<MyClass>() { CallBase = true };

      myClassMock.Verify(v => v.Method1(par1, par2), Times.Once);
      myClassMock.Verify(v => v.Method2(It.IsAny<string>(), out ?, out ?), Times.AtMost(3));
   }
}
```

---

В зависимости от некоторого условия, количество вызовов `Method2` не должно превышать 3. Тест проверяет, срабатывает ли эта логика для конкретного запроса или нет.

Проблема в том, что невозможно установить все возможные варианты для выходных параметров и тут мне бы подошла конструкция с `It.IsAny<>()`, однако для `out` параметров это не работает.

Есть ли какие-то варианты для подобных кейсов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. **Простой** — передать неиспользуемую переменную (*дискарды — `_`, к
   сожалению, не поддерживаются в выражениях*).

   ```
   byte b;
   string s;
   myClassMock.Verify(
       v => v.Method2(It.IsAny<string>(), out b, out s),
       Times.AtMost(3));
   ```
2. **Непростой** (*для версий Moq 4.8+*) — ввод `ref`-матчей, как выяснилось — для `out` параметров
   они тоже подходят.

   ```
   myClassMock.Verify(
       v => v.Method2(It.IsAny<string>(),
                      out It.Ref<byte>.IsAny,
                      out It.Ref<string>.IsAny),
       Times.AtMost(3));
   ```

Во втором варианте следует помнить, что для `out`-параметров реальный матчинг не происходит, следовательно такой код может ввести в заблуждение и использовать его следует с осторожностью. По этой причине второй вариант [не рекомендуется к использованию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984876/4269118).